# When accessing SQL Server from C#, the database becomes "recover pending"

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio

Please understand that English is awkward using a translator.

To access SQL Server in C#, I coded as follows.
When I debuged the following code in Visual Studio, the database went into "recover pending" state.

The SQL Server I am using is Express Edition.
Please tell me how to not "recover pending" when accessing SQL Server's Database from C#.

```
public void DataConnect()
        {
            SqlConnection sconnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\northwnd.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;");

     
            sconnection.Open();

            try
            {
                using (dta.OrdersTableAdapter ta = new dta.OrdersTableAdapter())
                {
                    northwndDataSet ds = new northwndDataSet();
                    ta.Fill(ds.Orders);
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            finally
            {
                sconnection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your code didn't do that. It sounds like the database had problems, and you simply kicked the tires hard enough for it to notice.

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log for related messages.

Comment: It seems an issue caused by SQL Server. Besides, what is the specific code of your "OrdersTableAdapter" class? How does it get `sconnection`? Refer to [SqlDataAdapter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1).

Answer (score 0):

The recovery pending status occurs in the following states:
1- running the sql server engine without the data files.
2- restart the sql server while the open transaction using the tempdb.
3- corrupted data files .

So the database is not falling in this status with any code to connect or execute query .